# Как для мобильного экрана расположить так элементы?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Размеры на схеме приблизительны, главное - расположение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, примерно так.
Цифры уже сами подкрутите

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.el1 {
  background: #ffedb9;
}

.el2 {
  background: #a4b7ff;
}

.el3 {
  background: #ffadd6;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .container>div {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .el1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
  }
  .el2 {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }
  .el3 {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="el1">el1</div>
  <div class="el2">el2</div>
  <div class="el3">el3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container{
    width: 55%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap:wrap-reverse;
}
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Наверху оказывается 3-ий элемент.